# MS Full text search adding association

Tags: c#, sql

I have a DB with company names and description. i have a full text search on name,description.

The questions is there any way i can associate words with other words. Let me explain

i have records like

**Name**
Whoo Whaa
**Description**
Best chinese in the world

**Name**
Steak Range
**Description**
Best hamburger in world

What i would like is if i search say "food" i must get these records so i need to somehow link hamburger and chinese to food. Is this possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need tags, just add a string column to your table called Tag and store food in there ( or even multiple tags comma separated). Then extend the FT index to also include the new column.

Comment: hmmm. yeah i can even have a tbl containing the links and as soon as my compy table gets updated/added i can dynamicly do tags for the records.